# Pair variables on Custom Field Type

Tags: custom-fields, tags

In the Custom Field Type, I've made separate table to store other information. So it means single field value contain many values in array. I want to use this array as pair tags on expressionengine.

like:-

```
{playlist}
    {playlist:videos}
    {playlist:titles}
{/playlist}
```

As playlist has multiple videos and titles.

http://postimg.org/image/60spnlykt/

http://postimg.org/image/c63h56cb9/

Comment: Please, improve your question. Is this a grid field? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: No this is Custom Field. This Custom field takes Youtube playlist Id and then generates all thumbnails of the playlist. But now all thumbnails are in Array and i want to loop this array in my twig structure like {playlist}{/playlist}.

Comment: Please Suggest me. How can i do ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure what you're looking for, since your question isn't very clear, but I'm taking a shot in the dark.

I think you're looking for a way to output your custom field type as EE template tags, as you say:

```
{playlist}
    {videos}
    {titles}
{/playlist}
```

To do something like this, you probably need to parse those variables using the template class. Use these references to refresh your knowledge of EE custom add-ons:

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/fieldtypes.html#development-reference

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/template.html#parsing-variables

Comment: I think he needs something like [this](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/fieldtypes.html#rendering-the-tag), but I don't have the necessary expertise to help.